Opinion dynamics with stubborness - a closed loop form of the ODE
I have an interesting opinion dynamics problem. I need to find the closed-loop form of an ODE that describes the dynamics of the opinions of agents in a network. These opinions are values on the interval $(0,1)$.
In the linear case, this has the form:
$\dot{p}(t) = Lp(t)$,
where $p$ is the vector of agents' opinions, and $L$ is the Laplacian of the network. This has the closed loop form $p(t)= e^{-Lt}p_0$.
Now in my case, I would like to use a function that describes the stubbornness, $\gamma(p_i):(0,1)\rightarrow (0,0.25)$. This stubbornness function has an inverted 'V' shape, so if the agent's opinion is close to $0$ or $1$ then the function value is close to $0$. If the opinion of the agents is close to $0.5$ then the stubbornness function has a value around $0.25$. A candidate function to this is $\gamma(p_i) = p_i(1-p_i)$.
In this case the dynamics is:
$\dot{p} = \Gamma(p)Lp$,
where $\Gamma(p)$ is a diagonal matrix where the i-th diagonal element is $\gamma(p_i)$.
Now my question is the following:
Is there a function that has a similar behavior as $\gamma(p_i) = p_i(1-p_i)$, but it also has a closed loop form of p(t)?
Note that I could not find a solution to $\dot{p} = \Gamma(p)Lp$ with $\gamma(p_i) = p_i(1-p_i)$. That is why I am looking for another similar function.

Any hint can be useful
